# Importar as bibliotecas javax.persistence e javax.inject

Tags: eclipse, maven

Como faço para importar as bibliotecas javax.persistence e javax.inject em um projeto maven?

Obs.: estou utilizando eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Todas as dependências destes dois `groupID` estão nos repositórios centrais, então de forma resumida, basta incluir as bibliotecas que você precisa ao seu `pom.xml`.

No caso do `groupId` [`javax.inject`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject) são apenas duas, um exemplo seria isto:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

Já as dependências com `groupId` [`javax.persistence`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence) são mais, um exemplo seria a da API de persistência:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Para incluir diretamente pelo Eclipse, clique com o botão direito sobre o projeto maven, `Maven > Add Dependency`, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Adicionar dependência]

No diálogo que será exibido, basta incluir as informações solicitadas, ou fazer a pesquisa por estes `groupId` que precisa, como no exemplo abaixo:

[image: Detalhes dependência]

Caso precise de alguma outra dependência, você pode em um indexador como o [MVNRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/)